# filtering on n() within summarise()

Tags: r, dplyr

I like being able to do filtering within a `summarise()` function, but it seems to explicitly require a dataframe variable in order to operate. For example:

```
mtcars %>%
summarise(n = n(),
          avg_mpg = mean(mpg),
          avg_mpg_cyl4 = mean(mpg[cyl == 4]))
```

I want to apply a filter within `n()` as well though to get the count of rows for a given condition. Something like this which gives me the total row count and the row count for `cyl == 4`:

```
mtcars %>%
summarise(n = n(),
          avg_mpg = mean(mpg),
          n_cyl4 = n()[cyl == 4],
          avg_mpg_cyl4 = mean(mpg[cyl == 4]))
```

Is there a syntactical change I can make or a function like `n()` that does this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
mtcars %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            avg_mpg = mean(mpg),
            n_cyl2 = sum(cyl == 4),
            avg_mpg_cyl2 = mean(mpg[cyl == 4]))

   n  avg_mpg n_cyl2 avg_mpg_cyl2
1 32 20.09062     11     26.66364
```